# Is it possible to know the tides of a particular location 50 years or 100 years from now?

Tags: tides

Assuming no change in sea level (for the sake of argument), is it possible to know the high and low tides a half century or more in the future?  Is information like this available to the general public?

Comment: Look at this question and answer: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/16501/11908 I don't think it is a duplicate, but if you read the answers there I think it will solve your question.

Comment: Camilo's comment is fair enough, but predictions would be reasonably accurate within 100 years because I think the forces and other factors such as earth rotation do not vary that much over that time frame.